csv vs json dataframes in golang, is there a difference?
Oddly, reading in the same data into a gota dataframe seems to be acting differently depending on whether I use dataframe.ReadJSON() or dataframe.ReadCSV(). It's not the same dataframe output (the only difference I can see from printing is that the order of the columns is switched, but there may be something else). It is necessary for the workflow of my project that the JSON one should behave like the CSV one.
Here's the pseudocode workflow, just so the code is a little easier to read when you dive in:

Check if the file is an xlsx or csv.
Use the appropriate method of converting the file into a dataframe for each.
Pass the dataframe into a function called processDF().

Here's the code.

    func callFile(path string, w2 fyne.Window, BT binding.UntypedList) {
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".xlsx") {
        xlfile, _ := xlsxreader.OpenFile(path)
        defer xlfile.Close()
        first_sheet := xlfile.Sheets[0]
        chosenSheet := binding.BindString(&first_sheet)
        radios := []*widget.FormItem{}
        radio := widget.NewRadioGroup(xlfile.Sheets, func(value string) {
            chosenSheet.Set(value)
        })
        rform := widget.NewFormItem("", radio)
        radios = append(radios, rform)
        header_description := "Pick which sheet you would like to analyze."
        dialog.ShowForm(header_description, "This sheet", "nvm", radios, func(b bool) {
            csheet, _ := chosenSheet.Get()
            var result []*map[string]interface{}
            result, _ = excel2json.GetExcelFilePath(path, csheet, nil)
            output := ""
            for _, val := range result {
                result, _ := json.Marshal(val)
                output = output + "," + string(result)
            }
            dicts, _ := strings.CutPrefix(output, ",")
            output = "[" + dicts + "]"
            fmt.Println("printing the json output")
            fmt.Println(output)
            csvDf := dataframe.ReadJSON(strings.NewReader(output))
            fmt.Printf("csvDf: %v\n", csvDf)
            processDF(csvDf, w2, BT)
        }, w2)
    } else {
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()
        csvDf := dataframe.ReadCSV(file)
        fmt.Printf("csvDf: %v\n", csvDf)
        processDF(csvDf, w2, BT)
    }
}



**Even if you can't help me debug, if you know a way of turning excel files into gota dataframes, that is a good answer by itself !!** 


Some libraries being used here : 
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/thedatashed/xlsxreader#readme-example-usage
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-gota/gota@v0.12.0/dataframe#ReadJSON
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/FerdinaKusumah/excel2json#GetExcelFileUrl

All help grandly appreciated. Thank you for your princely debugging skills. 


In CSV and XLS the fields have an inherent order (the order in the table), in JSON not. So you expect the same behavior in a place where the input formats have different capabilities, specifically you expect order where an input format does not provide order.

@SteffenUllrich I see. So JSON is not likely to be a good method of converting xlsx to a dataframe. That's a good thing to know. I would still like to know the proper way of doing that. Do you know?
